# Run second site in the same VM: Is it possible?

Tags: virtual-machine

I would like to run all my Drupal 8 sites in one Vagrant VM instead of just one. Is this possible?

I tried to remove the default drupal site from the "web" folder and pulled(git) 2 of my current probject into it.

For any reason drush does not recongnize the drupal roots as proper drupal sites.

I am not sure how other modules react...  Is it normal to create each time a new VM for each Site you are developing. Seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is *possible*, but take it from me as a guy who did it for about 12 sites - it gets tedious fast to manage it.

Setting up and tearing down VMs is so fast and cheap, it's simply more practical to me to create one per project. It's less to manage, and it just becomes a 'part' of the project codebase (you can fetch Drupal VM with Composer now for example, or download and keep it in a 'tools' folder outside of docroot).

Also it does not sound like you are setting up Drupal VM properly... I suggest re-reading the docs or posting more information.

Comment: I thought it would be a performance problem to run a hand full VMs at the same time, as resources must be copied over and so forth. 

I encounter already with one Vagrant/ Virtualbox VM worse performance than with AMPPS for example. I wanted to keep it easy.

Comment: Why run them all at the same time?

Comment: copying over configurations, css, php code, inspecting html... many reasons. Its just better to have the ability to work with two sites at the same time. 

Also sometimes other people of my team have to work on my machine to fill in content for example, while I need to work on another project.

Comment: Why can't they run VMs themselves? Kind of the whole point. Then have staging servers for content entry.

Comment: They are not developers. They fiill the sites just with content / text, images and so on. As far as its not simple to copy over nodes from one database to another this is also no option for d8.

We need to have one test/dev server that is useable over the local network.  

I guess I have to stick then to Ampps. 
One last question... Is the Vagrant/VBox solution performancewise faster than for example a xampp or mamp solution with you?